# Zipline Fundamental data

Tags: python, zipline, quantopian

Does Zipline have the same fundamental data access as quantopian, if not how do I 
access it?

```
from quantopian.pipeline.data import Fundamentals
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Only accessible through Quantopians platform as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

Zipline comes with builtin Equity data, but does not come with builtin Fundamentals. You can access equity using:

```
from zipline.pipeline.data import EquityPricing
```

The default quantopian-quandl data bundle, which zipline comes with and is not dependent on Quantopian being live, is a repackaged Quandl WIKI dataset.

[Documentation here](https://zipline.ml4trading.io/bundles.html). (Note: zipline.io is down, so documentation link is a mirror.)